# How do I create sliding windows append the dict that have the highest threshold of 70?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I create a sliding window using dict, if within each sliding window has appended the highest threshold of `>=70?`?

For example:

```py
# First window (3 block): {1: 8.571, 2: 42.857, 3: 70.143}
# Check if there ` >= 70`, if yes

# Next window: {3: 70.143, 4: 42.857, 5: 71.429}
# slide the window (3 block) to `{3: 70.143}` 
# and check if there any number higher than {3: 70.143} if yes  append `{5: 71.429}`

# Next window start from : {6: 35.714, 7: 42.857, 8: 35.714}
# if no move to the next windown (3 block) and so on...


x = {1: 8.571, 2: 42.857, 3: 70.143, 4: 42.857, 5: 71.429, 6: 35.714, 7: 42.857, 8: 35.714, 9: 82.857, 10: 50.0}

a = []

int =  iter(x)  # ?

q = deque(itertools.islice(int, 3-1), maxlen=3)

for i in int:
    q.append(i)

print(q)
```

Output:

```py
deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
deque([2, 3, 4], maxlen=3)
deque([3, 4, 5], maxlen=3)
deque([4, 5, 6], maxlen=3)
deque([5, 6, 7], maxlen=3)
deque([6, 7, 8], maxlen=3)
deque([7, 8, 9], maxlen=3)
deque([8, 9, 10], maxlen=3)
```

#### want to get:

```py
#new list:
a = {5: 71.429}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you want dict or list.

```
x= {1: 70, 2: 20, 3 : 30, 4 : 40, 5 : 50, 6 : 60, 7 : 70, 8 : 80, 9: 90, 10 :100}
keys = list(x.keys())
for i in keys:
    if x[i] != 70:
        del x[i]

print(x)
```

Comment: @user14911241 Thank you. I want to do a sliding window of 3 blocks slide through the dict and check if every window had the value of 70 than append if have.

Answer (score 0):

This is work as you expected, and you prob. don't need `deque` in your `sample input`:

```
dc = {1: 70, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60,
     7: 70, 8 : 80, 9: 90, 10 : 100}

ans = []

#int =  iter(x)  # Don't use built-ins 'int` as variable name; maybe `it`?


#q = deque(itertools.islice(int, 3-1), maxlen=3)`


for k, val in dc.items():
    if val == 70:
        dc_str = f'{k}:{val}'.format(k, val)
        
        ans.append(dc_str)

print(ans)
```

Output:

```
['1:70', '7:70']
```

Comment: Daniel Hao. Thank you. I edit the question do you know how to get the highest threshold of <=70 sliding?